# Correlating values between to columns

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm a novice Excel user. Here's my problem. =COUNTIF('Roll-up'!$C:$C,B2) provides me with the total number of times value B2 (part number) appears in database C:C (corresponding list of part numbers)

What I need is to associate Roll-up column C with it's assigned "quantity" in  in column E. Then I need take the combined total of all the associated values in Column E for a total quantity.

???does that make sense. I confused myself further.

Comment: can you add screenshot to make the question more clear?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the `SUMIF()` function. The syntax is

=SUMIF(Range,Criteria,[SumRange])

So, according to your description you want to sum column E where column C equals the value in B2. That translates to

```
=SUMIF('Roll-up'!$C:$C,B2,'Roll-up'!$E:$E)
```

Comment: OMG...thank you!!!  Even more for providing the syntax in the explanation.

Comment: If that solves your puzzle, please mark the answer as explained in the [tour](http://superuser.com/tour)